# Join table with itself based on the condition t-sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, group-by

I'd appreciate if someone could help me with my query.
I have a table containing `Currencies` and `Amounts` for each currency. 
My first query is:

```
select Currency,  SUM(Amount) amnt from [MyTable] 
where CODE in(410, 420) 
group by Currency
```

So, I get:

```
Currency | amnt
USD      | 15
```

I want to show all available currencies from my table and to join them with this result (amount for these currencies must be null)

```
Currency | amnt
USD      | 15
EUR      | 
AED      |
```

I get the list of all currencies by query:

```
select currency from [MyTable] group by currency
```

So, How can I join these two queries?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Currency, SUM(CASE WHEN a.CODE IN (410, 420) THEN a.Amount ELSE 0 END) amnt 
FROM MyTable a 
GROUP BY a.Currency
```

**OR**

```
SELECT A.Currency, SUM(B.Amount) amnt 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Currency FROM MyTable) A
LEFT JOIN MyTable B ON A.Currency = B.Currency AND B.CODE IN (410, 420)
GROUP BY A.Currency
```

**OR**

```
SELECT A.Currency, SUM(B.Amount) amnt 
FROM (SELECT Currency FROM MyTable GROUP BY Currency) A
LEFT JOIN MyTable B ON A.Currency = B.Currency AND B.CODE IN (410, 420)
GROUP BY A.Currency
```